# How calculate growth rate in long format data frame?

Tags: r, math, dataframe

With data structured as follows...

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
      Year=rep(2010:2015,2),Value=1:12)
```

I'm having a tough time creating a growth rate column (by year) within category. Can anyone help with code to create something like this...

```
Category Year Value Growth  
    A   2010    1   
    A   2011    2   1.000  
    A   2012    3   0.500  
    A   2013    4   0.333  
    A   2014    5   0.250  
    A   2015    6   0.200  
    B   2010    7     
    B   2011    8   0.143  
    B   2012    9   0.125  
    B   2013    10  0.111  
    B   2014    11  0.100  
    B   2015    12  0.091
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For these sorts of questions ("how do I compute XXX by category YYY")? there are always solutions based on `by()`, the `data.table()` package, and `plyr`.  I generally prefer `plyr`, which is often slower, but (to me) more transparent/elegant.

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
  Year=rep(2010:2015,2),Value=1:12)


library(plyr)
ddply(df,"Category",transform,
         Growth=c(NA,exp(diff(log(Value)))-1))
```

The main difference between this answer and @krlmr's is that I am using a geometric-mean trick (taking differences of logs and then exponentiating) while @krlmr computes an explicit ratio.

Mathematically, `diff(log(Value))` is taking the differences of the logs, i.e. `log(x[t+1])-log(x[t])` for all `t`.  When we exponentiate that we get the ratio `x[t+1]/x[t]` (because `exp(log(x[t+1])-log(x[t])) = exp(log(x[t+1]))/exp(log(x[t])) = x[t+1]/x[t]`).  The OP wanted the fractional change rather than the multiplicative growth rate (i.e. `x[t+1]==x[t]` corresponds to a fractional change of zero rather than a multiplicative growth rate of 1.0), so we subtract 1.

I am also using `transform()` for a little bit of extra "syntactic sugar", to avoid creating a new anonymous function.

Comment: Wha what? Can you run that use of `exp` and `log` by me again please??

Comment: @SlowLearner: log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b). Now apply exp.

Comment: I wonder: Is there a more generic `diff` function somewhere that would accept a two-parameter function as argument?

Comment: Now there is: [`kimisc::gdiff`](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc). See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19977975/946850).

Comment: I like this and would like to point out that the `diff` function takes a *lag* argument. Thus, with quarterly data, one could define a function like `f <- function(x, lag=1) c(rep(NA,lag), exp(diff(log(x),lag=lag))-1)` and use it with `lag=4`, say.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `dplyr` package:

```
> df %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(Growth = (Value - lag(Value))/lag(Value))
```

which will produce the following result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Category [2]
   Category  Year Value  Growth
   <fct>    <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1 A         2010     1 NA     
 2 A         2011     2  1     
 3 A         2012     3  0.5   
 4 A         2013     4  0.333 
 5 A         2014     5  0.25  
 6 A         2015     6  0.2   
 7 B         2010     7 NA     
 8 B         2011     8  0.143 
 9 B         2012     9  0.125 
10 B         2013    10  0.111 
11 B         2014    11  0.1   
12 B         2015    12  0.0909
```

Answer (score 7):

Using R base function (`ave`)

```
> dfdf$Growth <- with(df, ave(Value, Category, 
                      FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)]) ))
> df
   Category Year Value     Growth
1         A 2010     1         NA
2         A 2011     2 1.00000000
3         A 2012     3 0.50000000
4         A 2013     4 0.33333333
5         A 2014     5 0.25000000
6         A 2015     6 0.20000000
7         B 2010     7         NA
8         B 2011     8 0.14285714
9         B 2012     9 0.12500000
10        B 2013    10 0.11111111
11        B 2014    11 0.10000000
12        B 2015    12 0.09090909
```

@Ben Bolker's answer is easily adapted to `ave`:

```
transform(df, Growth=ave(Value, Category, 
                         FUN=function(x) c(NA,exp(diff(log(x)))-1)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Very easy with `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Category),
      function (d) {
        d$Growth <- c(NA, tail(d$Value, -1) / head(d$Value, -1) - 1)
        d
      }
)
```

We have two problems here:

1. Splitting by category
2. Computing the growth rate

`ddply` is the workhorse, the split and the function to compute the growth rate is defined by parameters to this function.

Comment: you beat me by 12 seconds.  I like my geometric-mean (`diff(log(x))`) approach, but yours works too.

Answer (score 3):

A more elegant variant based on Ben's idea with the new `gdiff` function in [my R package](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc):

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
  Year=rep(2010:2015,2),Value=1:12)

library(plyr)
ddply(df, "Category", transform,
      Growth=c(NA, kimisc::gdiff(Value, FUN = `/`)-1))
```

Here, `gdiff` is used to compute a lagged rate (instead of a lagged difference as `diff` would).

Answer (score 1):

Many years later: the [tsbox](https://www.tsbox.help/) package aims to work with all kind of time series objects, including data frames, and offers a standard time series toolkit. Thus, calculating growth rates is as simple as:

```r
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
      Year=rep(2010:2015,2),Value=1:12)

library(tsbox)
ts_pc(df)
#> [time]: 'Year' [value]: 'Value' 
#>    Category       Year      Value
#> 1         A 2010-01-01         NA
#> 2         A 2011-01-01 100.000000
#> 3         A 2012-01-01  50.000000
#> 4         A 2013-01-01  33.333333
#> 5         A 2014-01-01  25.000000
#> 6         A 2015-01-01  20.000000
#> 7         B 2010-01-01         NA
#> 8         B 2011-01-01  14.285714
#> 9         B 2012-01-01  12.500000
#> 10        B 2013-01-01  11.111111
#> 11        B 2014-01-01  10.000000
#> 12        B 2015-01-01   9.090909
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `collapse` available in CRAN provides an easy and fully C/C++ based solution to these kinds of problems: with the generic function `fgrowth` and the associated growth operator `G`:

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
      Year=rep(2010:2015,2),Value=1:12)

library(collapse)
G(df, by = ~Category, t = ~Year)

   Category Year   G1.Value
1         A 2010         NA
2         A 2011 100.000000
3         A 2012  50.000000
4         A 2013  33.333333
5         A 2014  25.000000
6         A 2015  20.000000
7         B 2010         NA
8         B 2011  14.285714
9         B 2012  12.500000
10        B 2013  11.111111
11        B 2014  10.000000
12        B 2015   9.090909

# fgrowth is more of a programmers function, you can do:

fgrowth(df$Value, 1, 1, df$Category, df$Year)
 [1]   NA 100.000000  50.000000  33.333333  25.000000  20.000000         NA  14.285714  12.500000  11.111111  10.000000   9.090909

# Which means: Calculate the growth rate of Value, using 1 lag, and iterated 1 time (you can compute arbitrary sequences of lagged / leaded and iterated growth rates with these functions), identified by Category and Year.
```

`fgrowth / G` also has methods for the `plm::pseries` and `plm::pdata.frame` classes available in the plm package.