# Calculating yearly growth-rates from quarterly, long form data in r

Tags: r, dataframe

My data takes the following form:

```
df <- data.frame(Sector=c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8)), Country = c(rep("USA", 16)),
                 Quarter=rep(1:8,2),Income=20:35)
df2 <- data.frame(Sector=c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8)), Country = c(rep("UK", 16)),
                 Quarter=rep(1:8,2),Income=32:47)
df <- rbind(df, df2)
```

What I want to do is to calculate the growth rate from the first quarter each year to the first quarter the second year, within country and sector. In the example above it would be the growth rate from quarter 1 to quarter 5. So for Sector A, in the USA, it would be (24/20)-1=0.2

I then want to append this data to the dataframe as a new column.

I looked at the solutions in:
[How calculate growth rate in long format data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824601/how-calculate-growth-rate-in-long-format-data-frame)

But didn't have the r-skills to get it to work if the lag is more then one time-unit. Any suggestions?

ADDITION

So what i want is the growth-rate, that is (24/20)-1=0.2 in the example below. Not 1-(24/20), which I first wrote. The desired output should look something like this:

```
  Sector Country Quarter Income     growth
   (fctr)  (fctr)   (int)  (int)      (dbl)
1       A     USA       1     20    NA
2       A     USA       2     21    NA
3       A     USA       3     22    NA
4       A     USA       4     23    NA
5       A     USA       5     24    0.2
6       A     USA       6     25    0.1904
7       A     USA       7     26    0.1818
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  #group by sector and country
  group_by(Sector, Country) %>%
  #calculate growth as (quarter / 5-period-lagged quarter) - 1
  mutate(growth = Income / lag(Income, 4) - 1)
```

Output

```
Source: local data frame [32 x 5]
Groups: Sector, Country [4]

   Sector Country Quarter Income    growth
   (fctr)  (fctr)   (int)  (int)     (dbl)
1       A     USA       1     20        NA
2       A     USA       2     21        NA
3       A     USA       3     22        NA
4       A     USA       4     23        NA
5       A     USA       5     24 0.2000000
6       A     USA       6     25 0.1904762
7       A     USA       7     26 0.1818182
8       A     USA       8     27 0.1739130
9       B     USA       1     28        NA
10      B     USA       2     29        NA
..    ...     ...     ...    ...       ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite what I was looking for. Except for the first for quarters, which will be missing, I'm looking to calculate a unique growth rate from t-4 for each row. Please see my addition! in the original post!

Comment: I tried on my real data now, and it worked like a charm. Very elegant solution. On question though, I'm not familiar with the operator %>% and it's quite un-google-ble. What does it do?

Comment: Happy to hear that :). Thanks!

Comment: It comes from the `magrittr` package. It allows for a clearer way to represent nested functions. The object on the left side of `%>%` is passed as the first argument to the function on the right. Type `help('%>%')` and there is a comprehensive example and description.

Answer (score 1):

```
df3 = copy(df)
df3$Quarter = df3$Quarter - 4
df = merge(df,df3,c('Sector','Country','Quarter'), suffixes = c('','_prev'), all.x = T)
df$growth = 1 - (df$Income_prev/df$Income


> df
   Sector Country Quarter Income Income_prev growth
1       A     USA       1     20          24     -4
2       A     USA       2     21          25     -4
3       A     USA       3     22          26     -4
4       A     USA       4     23          27     -4
5       A     USA       5     24          NA     NA
6       A     USA       6     25          NA     NA
7       A     USA       7     26          NA     NA
8       A     USA       8     27          NA     NA
9       A      UK       1     32          36     -4
10      A      UK       2     33          37     -4
11      A      UK       3     34          38     -4
12      A      UK       4     35          39     -4
13      A      UK       5     36          NA     NA
14      A      UK       6     37          NA     NA
15      A      UK       7     38          NA     NA
16      A      UK       8     39          NA     NA
17      B     USA       1     28          32     -4
18      B     USA       2     29          33     -4
19      B     USA       3     30          34     -4
20      B     USA       4     31          35     -4
21      B     USA       5     32          NA     NA
22      B     USA       6     33          NA     NA
23      B     USA       7     34          NA     NA
24      B     USA       8     35          NA     NA
25      B      UK       1     40          44     -4
26      B      UK       2     41          45     -4
27      B      UK       3     42          46     -4
28      B      UK       4     43          47     -4
29      B      UK       5     44          NA     NA
30      B      UK       6     45          NA     NA
31      B      UK       7     46          NA     NA
32      B      UK       8     47          NA     NA
>
```