# R: is there a simple growth function?

Tags: r

I run into this problem again and again and I've always forgotten my last solution by the time. Is there a simple growth function implemented in R base which can easily be used in `data.tables` and `data.frames` with `ddply` etc? Something like:

```
x <- c(rnorm(10))

mygrowth <- function(x){
 (x-c(NA,x)[-length(x)])/c(NA,x)[-length(x)]*100}
cbind(x,mygrowth(x))
```

which avoids logs as opposed to in this [otherwise great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824601/how-calculate-growth-rate-in-long-format-data-frame) and can directly be used in `data.table`*. I feel a little stupid asking this but I searched for it quite a bit and found nothing implemented outside time series objects.

Somehow I can't imagine that this is not implemented. Or am I going at it the wrong way and should I instead use time series objects inside my `data.table` although I'm running `plm` commands?

*:
p.s.:

```
    Data <- data.table(iris)
    Data$growth <- Data[,mygrowth(Sepal.Length),by=Species][,V1]
```

Comment: The zoo package has an arithmetic=FALSE argument to diff.zoo.  It does use logs internally.   Why don't you want to use logs?

Comment: because I oftentimes have negative numbers. Why should I use logs? Log differences just work by a first order taylor approximation, right? So outliers would be another problem if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: exp(log(x1) - log(x2)) = exp(log(x1/x2)) = x1/x2 exactly (except for computer arithmetic which affects any floating calculation).