# How to compute growth rate (1- and 3-year horizon) from panel data in R

Tags: r, missing-data, rate, panel-data

I've a panel dataset of several banks, each from 1997 to 2015, with annual observations s.t.:

```
CODE      COUNTRY      YEAR      LOANS_NET      ...other variables
671405      AT         1997       39028938
671405      AT         1998       41033237
671405      AT         1999       35735062
...
...
671405      AT         2015      130701872
...
30885R      DE         2004      200024673
...
...
```

Using R, I need to compute additional two columns:

1) LOANS_NET growth rate at 1-year horizon

2) LOANS_NET growth rate at 3-years horizon, which must be annualized, once calculated.

E.g.:

```
Loan Growth 3-year = [Bank's(i) LOANS_NET Year(t) / Bank's(i) LOANS_NET Year(t-3)] -1
```

nb: data contains lots of missing values, code must consider that issue! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dan Do you use any packages? I recommend you using zoo and data.table packages and transform dates in the following way:

```
DT[, YearNumeric := as.numeric(YEAR)]
DT[, PreviousYearLoanNet := .SD[match(YearNumeric - 1, .SD$YearNumeric), LOANS_NET], by=CODE]
```

Here, you create a column with previous (-1 year) loan values. Then you create a new column with growth:

```
DT[,Growth1Y:= (YEARLOANNET- PreviousYearLoanNet)/PreviousYearLoanNet]
```

And then you do whatever you want:) Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much mate!

Just one question: do you have any idea about doing the same purpose using plyr package? because I tried using codes reported [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824601/how-calculate-growth-rate-in-long-format-data-frame) but the results are so different each other :S

Comment: What is different precisely? I don't have much experience with dplyr but I guess you can transform it with ddply function, right?

Comment: I used this script to obtain 3-year growth rate column: 

    data1<-transform(df, Growth=ave(Value, Category, 
                         FUN=function(x) c(NA,exp(diff(log(x),lag = 3)-1)))

but the rates are really different if compared them with ones whose came out from your procedure. I suppose I made a mistake since I'm not sure the script right above is correct..

Comment: The function that you use, uses geometric growth if I'm not mistaken, right? My procedure uses arithmetic growth, i.e. (t+1/t)/t. I also calculated it for 1 year, and you calculated 3 year geometric average growth rate.

Comment: You're tremendously right, my fault. Thus I think it would be interesting analysing effects on y (the dependent variable I'm going to study) both with arithmetic and the geometric growth rates, one as control as the other. :) Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark my answer as "solved" :)